How to get the use-sound hook working with Parcel?
I've started building React websites with Parcel and want to use the use-sound hook, but Parcel is giving me issues.
Specifically, I am seeing the following error:
ReferenceError: HowlerGlobal is not defined (Parcel 2)
With the following code snippet:
import React from 'react';

import useSound from 'use-sound';
import submitSound from '../../sounds/compute.wav';

function SubmitButton() {
  const [playSubmit] = useSound(submitSound);

  return (
    <button onClick={playSubmit}>{'Submit'}</button>
  );
}

export default SubmitButton;


What is the code you are working with? What are any of the issues you face? No one can help you if they don't know what the problem is or what you are doing to produce it. Please [edit] to include actual details about a specific issue or problem you have and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

@DrewReese I was able to resolve the issue for myself and posted this as a Q&A for people who run across the same issues (see answer below). I will include more detail so that this can be searched for more easily when I have a minute.

Here is what worked for me:
Steps:

create a .parcelrc file in the root directory with the following contents:

{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.{au,wav,mp3}": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
  }
}





(a.) run npm install howler
(b.) run npm install use-sound


at the bottom level of your package.json (e.g. right after dependencies), include the following line:

"alias": {
    "howler": "howler/dist/howler.core.min.js"
},


Upload your sounds to src/sounds/[example_sound.mp3]

Finally, here's my code snippet using the sound effect:


import React from 'react';

import useSound from 'use-sound';
import submitSound from '../../sounds/compute.wav';

function SubmitButton() {
  const [playSubmit] = useSound(submitSound);

  return (
    <button onClick={playSubmit}>{'Submit'}</button>
  );
}

export default SubmitButton;


